# RDP Session Assigned Keyboard Shortcut to Open desktop Shortcut not working

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I have an RDP Session that has application shorctuts on the desktop that have assigned Keyboard Shortcuts to initiate the opening of an application. For what ever reason these do not work when we moved from 2003 to 2008 R2 terminal servers. If I use the console /Admin switch they work.

this is what the keyboard hook is set on the 2003 and 2008 RDP files.

`keyboardhook:i:2`

Any ideas?